# How to order rows in dataframe with a new piping in r?

Tags: r

I want to use a new R pipe |> for the script like this:

```
df <- data.frame (letter=c(rep("a",3), rep("b",3), rep("c",2)),
                    number = c(1,3,4,7,6,2,5,8))
df <- df[which(df$letter !="c"),]
df <- df[order(df$number),]
```

I tried this

```
df <- data.frame (letter=c(rep("a",3), rep("b",3), rep("c",2)),
                  number = c(1,3,4,7,6,2,5,8)) |>
  df[which(df$letter !="c"),] |>
  df[order(df$number),]
```

But got an error

> Error: function '[' not supported in RHS call of a pipe

How to use |> in this case to filter and order rows in a dataframe?

Comment: The pipe pipes the object into the next function as a first argument, but when simply slicing the data with `[ ]` you don't really call a function which has the input data as first argument.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `[` as a function then apply `|>` operator as follows

```
df <- df |> (\(x)`[`(x,which(df$letter !="c") ,))()

df |> (\(x)`[`(x,order(df$number) ,))()
```

- output

```
  letter number
1      a      1
6      b      2
2      a      3
3      a      4
5      b      6
4      b      7
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is an alternative suggestion. Not directly related to the provided code:

```
library(dplyr)

df |> 
  filter(letter != "c") |>
  arrange(number)

  letter number
1      a      1
6      b      2
2      a      3
3      a      4
5      b      6
4      b      7
```

Answer (score 1):

Another approach is to write a pipeable function to use instead of `[` that would work in most instances, instead of case-by-case.
A first try is `DF <- function(x, ...) x[...]` but this isn't great because you still need `df$` inside the brackets and that refers to the original data.frame, not the piped one.  So,

```
DF <- function(x, ...) eval(substitute(x[...]), envir = x)
df |> 
  DF(letter != "c", ) |> 
  DF(order(number), )
```

This allows dropping the `df$` and doing a true pipe.
The result is:

```
  letter number
1      a      1
6      b      2
2      a      3
3      a      4
5      b      6
4      b      7
```

(This idea came from what the dev version of the data.table package is doing with the DT() function.)

Also, `subset(letter != "c")` works just fine for the first part, then you don't need the extra comma.